# Host key verification failed

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I have a script that fetches files from a server using this code to open a session.

```
sftp -o port="port" -o IdentityFile="private_key_location" "username@remote_host"
```

Running it manually successfully downloads the files.

But when I use scheduler to run the script, It fails and prompts

```
No RSA host key is known for [remote_host]:port and you have requested strict checking
Host key verification failed.
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

My `private_key_location` is also accessible by another user.
I have read that the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` where the script was executed may not have the host that I am connecting in my `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

How do I configure the script so that it will not fail when it is run by another user given that it still have access to my `private_key_location`?

Thanks.

Comment: Try *su -c 'sftp...' YourUserName*.

Comment: Hi @MariusMatutiae, can this be done without inputting the password? As I would not like that my password will be accessible to all. Thanks,

Comment: As @MariusMatutiae indicates, logging in interactively as the specified user once will cache the host key in the users keystore. Note that you should only have to do this once. and the username in question is not the user that the process works under, but the one that it does not.

Answer (score 8):

First thing you can do is run `sftp` with option `StrictHostKeyChecking` set to "no".

```
sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o port="port" -o IdentityFile="private_key_location" "username@remote_host"
```

This options will disable remote host key check.

Otherwise you can create global `known_hosts` file. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/making-ssh-hosts-global-to-all-the-users-on-the-computer) for how to do it.

Comment: It resulted into a "Permission denied (publickey)."

Comment: User authentification happens after remote host key check, which means, that your first problem with `known_hosts` file is solved.